# why there is no output of the test code?

Tags: magento

In Magento CMS page, I add code:

```
 {{block type=”core/template” name=”review” template=”catalog/product/reviewall.phtml”}}
```

the URL key is **review.html**

then add file reviewall.phtml(app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/reviewall.phtml)

then add test code in its file.

```
echo "hello world";
```

when I access URL `mysiteurl/review.html` there is no hello world output. Why? How to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right however your quotes look like unicode closing quotes - replace the quotes then you should be fine.